# Writing Classes: Creating a RightTriangle class that works with the given tester

Tags: java

I am doing an assignment and kinda lost now. The assignment requires me to make a RightTriangle class that works with the given driver. Here are the details:

Your RightTriangle class will need two constructors:

- A parameterized constructor that takes the two legs of the triangle and calculates the hypotenuse.  Throw an exception if either leg is less than or equal to zero.
- A default constructor that sets the two legs to 1 and calculates the hypotenuse. This constructor should call your parameterized constructor using the "this" command.

Your RightTriangle class will need the following public methods:

- A getArea() method that returns a double
- A getPerimeter() method that returns a double
- A toString method() that returns a String in the following format: "A right triangle with edges 1.0, 1.0, and hypotenuse 1.4142135623730951."

---

**RightTriangleDriver.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class RightTriangleDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /*
            Menu:
                1 - test default constructor and toString
                2 - test parameterized constructor and toString
                3 - test getArea
                4 - test getPerimeter
        */

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = kb.nextInt();

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:  //1 - test default constructor and toString
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Testing default constructor, then toString()");
                    RightTriangle r = new RightTriangle();
                    System.out.println("Got: " + r);
                }
                catch(Throwable ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("\tgot:      " + ex);
                }
                break;

            case 2:  //2 - test parameterized constructor and toString
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Testing parameterized constructor, then toString()");
                    double side1 = kb.nextDouble();
                    double side2 = kb.nextDouble();
                    RightTriangle r = new RightTriangle(side1, side2);
                    System.out.println("Got: " + r);
                }
                catch(Throwable ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("Got: " + ex);
                }
                break;

            case 3:  //3 - test getArea
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Testing getArea()");
                    double side1 = kb.nextDouble();
                    double side2 = kb.nextDouble();
                    RightTriangle r = new RightTriangle(side1, side2);
                    System.out.println("Got: " + r.getArea());
                }
                catch(Throwable ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("Got: " + ex);
                }
                break;

            case 4:  //4 - test getPerimeter
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Testing getPerimeter()");
                    double side1 = kb.nextDouble();
                    double side2 = kb.nextDouble();
                    RightTriangle r = new RightTriangle(side1, side2);
                    System.out.println("Got: " + r.getPerimeter());
                }
                catch(Throwable ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("Got: " + ex);
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("I don't understand your request");
        }
    }
}
```

**This is what I've got so far**

```
 public class RightTriangle
{

    private double side1;
    private double side2;


    //constructors
    public RightTriangle()
    {
        this(1.0, 1.0);
    }

    public RightTriangle(double s1, double s2)
    {
        if(s1 > 0 && s2 > 0)
            side1 = s1;
            side2 = s2;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("All triangle edges must have positive length");
    }


    //Methods

    public String toString()
    {
        return  "A right triangle with edges " + side1 + ", " + side2 + " , and hypotenuse " + Math.sqrt((side1 * side1) + (side2 * side2)) + ".";
    }


    //get Area
    public double getArea()
    {
        return side1 * side2 / 2;
    }


    //get Perimeter
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return side1 + side2 + Math.sqrt((side1 * side1) + (side2 * side2));
    }

    //get hypotenuse
    public double getHypotenuse()
    {
        return Math.sqrt((side1 * side1) + (side2 * side2));
    }
```

- I'm stuck because I don't know how to make them work with all tests. Any advice would be appreciated!.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed something but is seems like you just need to override toString for RightTriangle according to the specifications in the assignment.

I can elaborate if you want to. I would have posted this as a comment if i had the reputation to do so.

EDIT:

```
RightTriangle r = new RightTriangle();
System.out.println("Got: " + r);
```

This code is from RightTriangleDriver. When `p`, a RightTriangle object is given to System.out.println, its `toString()` value is printed.

It is therefore identical to the following:

```
RightTriangle r = new RightTriangle();
System.out.println("Got: " + r.toString());
```

From the specifications in the assignment:

> Your RightTriangle class will need the following public methods:
>   ...
>   A toString method() that returns a String in the following format: "A right triangle with edges 1.0, 1.0, and hypotenuse 1.4142135623730951."

EDIT 2: A more detailed description of toString

`toString` exists for every object in java. By default, your own classes' `toString` methods will return something like "RightTriangle@l13e8ed".

In the specification for this assignment, you were tasked to make your toString() return a specific description of the object rather than the default. We achieve this by *overriding* the `toString` method.

When you want to Override a method, you create a new one with the same declaration (Return type, name, and parameter types) as the one in the superclass. There are more advanced rules but in general you just create a method with the same declaration. In this case, creating a `public String toString()` in `RightTriangle` will override the toString() that exists by default:

```
public String toString(){
    return "A right triangle with edges " + firstSide + ", " + secondSide +", and hypotenuse " + hypotenuse + ".";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can contact you?

Comment: It is in the spirit of Stack Overflow to try to clarify a question, and to answer the question, on the site itself. This allows the question and its answers to help future readers - if help is rendered privately, then in most of those cases, neither party will come back to give us what the solution was.

Comment: @halfer I know, but Xyexs mentioned he didn't have reputation to do so (if I wasn't mistaken).

Comment: @Apples I'm 1 rep off.

I'll edit the answer though.

Comment: @Xyexs Could you please elaborate more? How do I override it?

Comment: @Xyexs Thank you very much. I'm still confused about the toString() method and the default constructor:  public RightTriangle(). Are they supposed to be the same thing in this assignment?

Comment: @Apples They're different. The constructor sets values when the object is instantiated and `toString` returns a string representation of the object. I will edit the answer.